# bootstrap-sweetalert with requireJS displays alertbox "Not valid"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, bower, sweetalert

I install bootstrap-sweetalert to my webapp through bower with -> $ bower install bootstrap-sweetalert <- and configure the requireConfig.js to make require listen to "sweetalert". When called, no matter what function I am trying to use from boostrap-sweetalert, the DOM displays an alertbox at the bottom of the page that display "Not valid" with an input field for some reason. It appears to be some sort of default alert, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The "strange" alertbox:

[image]

My JS look like this, trying to display a simple message from bootstrap-sweetalert.

```
    define(function (require) {

    'use strict';



    var $ = require('jquery');

    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var _ = require('underscore');

    var html = require('text!./template.html');

    var template = require('util/template');

    var numberFormatter = require('util/formatter/number');



    var swalOnline = require('https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js');

    var swal = require('sweetalert');



    var viewMaker = function (clientId, caseId, periodId, accountingId, eCheck) {

        var view;

        var View = Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function () {

                view = this;

            },

            render: function () {

            template.render(html, {eCheck:eCheck, numberFormatter: numberFormatter,}, view.el);



            swal("Message outside button");

            var $saveButton = view.$el.find('button[data-id="savehome-button"]');

                    $saveButton.click(function (event) {

                        // Disable native actions on save button click

                        event.preventDefault();

                        swal("Message inside button");

                    });

                return view;

            }

        });

        view = new View();

        return view;

    };
    return viewMaker;
});
```

requirejs.config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'spa',
    paths: {
        'backbone': 'bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'text': 'bower_components/text/text',
        'underscore': 'bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        'bootstrap': 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
        'moment': 'bower_components/moment/moment',
        'datepicker': 'bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker',
        'slider': 'bower_components/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider',
        'leaflet': 'bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet',
        'leaflet.markercluster': 'bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster',
    'sweetalert': 'bower_components/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            'exports': '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            'deps': [ 'underscore' ],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: [ 'jquery' ]
        },
        'datepicker': {
            'deps': [ 'jquery' ],
            'exports': '$.fn.datepicker'
        },
        'leaflet.markercluster': {
            'deps': ['leaflet']
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function (app) {
    require(['bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.sv'], function () {
        app.start();
    });
});
```

Strange thing is that if I were to use swalOnline variable instead it works fine. Which takes use of require('https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js');

Answer (score 0):

Try to include to your code *css* from *bootstrap-sweetalert*, the error will disappear.

P.S. In the example code, you are using two different packages. So it works.
The package that are added to the code via cdn is original *sweetalert* package (swalOnline variable). The one that is added via bower is *bootstrap-sweetalert* (swal variable).

Comment: I am new to this project, any suggestions for how to add it to my CSS code? It appears this project don't really deal with CSS

Comment: If the project has bundlers such as *gulp*, *webpack*, then through them. Otherwise you can add in html-file following link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.css